# Combining two pytorch functions into one

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two functions like this (code source of the functions is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/phlippe/uvadlc_notebooks/blob/master/docs/tutorial_notebooks/tutorial7/GNN_overview.ipynb#scrollTo=eZKw8LPNrNFS)):

```
device = torch.device('cuda')
dataset = TUDataset(root='/tmp/MUTAG', name='MUTAG', use_node_attr=True)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
train_dataset = dataset #just for testing
val_dataset = dataset
test_dataset = dataset
graph_train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=True) 
graph_val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=8) 
gnn_layer_by_name = {
    "GCN": geom_nn.GCNConv,
    "GAT": geom_nn.GATConv,
    "GraphConv": geom_nn.GraphConv
}

class GCNLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, c_in, c_out):
        super().__init__()
        self.projection = nn.Linear(c_in, c_out)
        
    def forward(self, node_feats, adj_matrix):
        num_neighbours = adj_matrix.sum(dim=-1, keepdims=True)
        node_feats = self.projection(node_feats)
        node_feats = torch.bmm(adj_matrix, node_feats)
        node_feats = node_feats / num_neighbours
        return node_feats


class GNNModel(nn.Module)
  
    def __init__(self, c_in, c_hidden, c_out, num_layers, activation_function, optimizer_name, learning_rate, dp_rate_linear,layer_name="GCN", **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        gnn_layer = gnn_layer_by_name[layer_name]
        
        layers = []
        activation_function = eval(activation_function) ##not great to use
        in_channels, out_channels = c_in, c_hidden
        for l_idx in range(num_layers-1):
            layers += [
                gnn_layer(in_channels=in_channels, 
                          out_channels=out_channels,
                          **kwargs),
                activation_function,
                nn.Dropout(p=dp_rate_linear)
            ]
            in_channels = c_hidden
        layers += [gnn_layer(in_channels=in_channels, 
                             out_channels=c_out,
                             **kwargs)]
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(layers)
    
    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        for l in self.layers:
            if isinstance(l, geom_nn.MessagePassing):
                x = l(x, edge_index)
            else:
                x = l(x)
        return x


class GraphGNNModel(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, c_in, c_hidden, c_out, dp_rate_linear,**kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.GNN = GNNModel(c_in=c_in, 
                            c_hidden=c_hidden, 
                            c_out=c_hidden,
                            dp_rate_linear = dp_rate_linear, 
                            **kwargs)
        self.head = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(p=dp_rate_linear),
            nn.Linear(c_hidden, c_out)
        )
    def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch_idx):
        x = self.GNN(x, edge_index)
        x = geom_nn.global_mean_pool(x, batch_idx) 
        x = self.head(x)
        return x
```

As you can see, I really don't need GNNModel and GraphGNNModel to be two separate functions, the second function is just adding a sequential layer to the end of the first function.

I tried combining the functions by doing:

```
class GNNModel(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, c_in, c_hidden, c_out, num_layers, activation_function, optimizer_name, learning_rate, dp_rate_linear,layer_name="GCN" ,**kwargs):
        """
        Inputs:
            c_in - Dimension of input features
            c_hidden - Dimension of hidden features
            c_out - Dimension of the output features. Usually number of classes in classification
            num_layers - Number of "hidden" graph layers
            layer_name - String of the graph layer to use
            dp_rate_linear - Dropout rate to apply throughout the network
            kwargs - Additional arguments for the graph layer (e.g. number of heads for GAT; i'm not using gat here)
            activation_function - Activation function
        """

        super().__init__()
        gnn_layer = gnn_layer_by_name[layer_name]
        
        layers = []

        activation_function = eval(activation_function) ##not great to use
        in_channels, out_channels = c_in, c_hidden
        for l_idx in range(num_layers-1):
            layers += [
                gnn_layer(in_channels=in_channels, 
                          out_channels=out_channels,
                          **kwargs),
                activation_function,
                nn.Dropout(p=dp_rate_linear)
            ]
            in_channels = c_hidden
        layers += [gnn_layer(in_channels=in_channels, 
                             out_channels=c_out,
                             **kwargs)]
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(layers)
    

        self.head = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(p=dp_rate_linear),
            nn.Linear(c_hidden, c_out)
        )

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        for l in self.layers:
            if isinstance(l, geom_nn.MessagePassing): #passing data between conv
                x = l(x, edge_index) #what is this
            else:
                x = l(x)

        x = self.GNN(x, edge_index)
        x = geom_nn.global_mean_pool(x, batch_idx) 
        x = self.head(x)
        return x
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: forward() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Could someone show me the correct way to combine these (the exact explanation of the code is in the Graph level tasks/graph classification of [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/phlippe/uvadlc_notebooks/blob/master/docs/tutorial_notebooks/tutorial7/GNN_overview.ipynb#scrollTo=eZKw8LPNrNFS)?

Comment: You have different forward functions, one takes 4 arg, one 3. `forward(self, x, edge_index, batch_idx)` in GraphGNNModel and `forward(self, x, edge_index)` in GNNModel. I think you are calling the wrong one later during the training. Please post the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `batch_idx` as param in your new `forward` function. I noted some other inconsistencies like, where is `geom_nn` being passed to the function? you probably want to use `self.geom_nn`, and for that you need to fix the `__init__()` part as well.

```
def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch_idx): #here you must pass batch_idx
    for l in self.layers:
        if isinstance(l, geom_nn.MessagePassing): #passing data between conv
            x = l(x, edge_index) #what is this
        else:
            x = l(x)

    x = self.GNN(x, edge_index)
    x = geom_nn.global_mean_pool(x, batch_idx) #here you use batch_idx
    #where is geom_nn coming from???
    x = self.head(x)
    return x
```